# The magic of ink tubes - Hydrophilic polymers?

Tags: polymers

First Chemistry SE post. I'm trying to make a capillary ink tube similar to the ones they used to have in chart recorders (here's an example of [a capillary tube patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US3102770)).

That is, an ink reservoir and a writing nib of some sort (probably felt tipped) connected with a long thin tube. What is the nature of that tube?

[image: Physioscribe Chart Recorder - We found one at a local tech salvage place, but minus the critical ink tube portion]*Physioscribe Chart Recorder - We found one at a local tech salvage place, but minus the critical ink tube portion*

I tried some plastic tube experiments to see if the tube would draw water-based ink up out of a reservoir, but it did not. Afterward, I research the material, and found the tube was made of teflon. Teflon is hydrophobic and so apparently discouraged capillary action.

So here are a series of questions:

1. Is there a thin tube material that will draw water-based ink up out of a reservoir?
2. What would this thin tube be made of? Some hydrophilic polymer? Something such as polyvinyl alcohol, poly vinyl pyrrolidone, or cellulose?
3. Are there common suppliers that make tube of this material? And where?
4. Finally, is there something I am totally missing that would work better?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome!  What was the inner diameter of the tubing used in your experiments and what was the tubing made of?  Do you know the inner diameter of the Teflon tubing used in the chart recorder?

Comment: I don't know what the tubes in the chart recorder were made of since they were missing, but it is unlikely they were teflon since it is hydrophobic and resists capillary action.  The ones I experimented with were 7mm to probably 0.5 mm. But they were teflon and didn't work.

Comment: In the sited patent, they used "... Saran which is the trade-mark given to a group of tough, flexible, thermo-plastics, containing polymeric vinylidene. "  I would browse through the online catalog of Sigma-Aldrich or of a capillary tubing specialty company like [Paradigm Polymers](http://www.paradigmoptics.com/capillary/capillary.html)